# How to close one specifc chrome profile with command line?

Tags: command-line, chromium

It is very easy to open specific profile with command line, which is like 'chrome.exe --profile-directory="Profile 2"'.

But if I have Profile 1 and Profile 2 open at the same time, each profile may have many tabs, how can I close one specifc profile, let's say, Profile 2 with command line (which means, Profile 1 should remain)?

The tabs don't matter. If I close one profile, all the tabs related to that profile will also be closed. The result should be just the same as that when we mannully click the close button of the window of the specific profile.

I didn't find any command line that can do that yet, and the way using taskkill also does not work, or I didn't find the correct way?